# World cup Python progam

Tags: python

I am working on a program that reads a text file containing a list of FIFA World Cup champions and determines, by the `world_cup_champions.txt` file shown below, the country that has won the most championships display the countries alphabetically. I am getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\CUP.py", line 8, in <module>
    for l in f2:
NameError: name 'f2' is not defined.
```

Here's my code:

```
def main():
    f2  = open("world_cup_champions.txt","r+")

dict_values ={}
temp_list = []
tmp_list2 = []

for l in f2:
    temp_list.append(l.strip())
    temp_list = temp_list[1:]


for val in temp_list:
    tmp_val = val.split(',')
    if tmp_val[1] not in dict_values:
        dict_values[tmp_val[1]] = 1
else:
    dict_values[tmp_val[1]] += 1

for key,value in dict_values.items():
    tmp_list2.append([key, value])


    tmp_list2.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    print(" Country " + " Wins " + "Years")
for val in tmp_list2:
    print(" " + val[0] + " " + str(val[1]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Is this verbatim from your code file? It looks like you need to indent everything from `dict_values ={}` to `print(" " + val[0] + " " + str(val[1]))`. Python uses the indent level to decide what block each line of code belongs to, so right now, all that code is being executed as if it is not part of `main()`

Answer (score 1):

`f2` is defined inside `def main()` which makes it local variable, when you call it in `for l in f2` the `f2` is outside the function so you need global variable to be called. If you really going to put everything inside main(), than you have to indent everything like this

```
def main():
    f2  = open("world_cup_champions.txt","r+")

    dict_values ={}
    temp_list = []
    tmp_list2 = []

    for l in f2:
        temp_list.append(l.strip())
        temp_list = temp_list[1:]


    for val in temp_list:
        tmp_val = val.split(',')
        if tmp_val[1] not in dict_values:
            dict_values[tmp_val[1]] = 1
    else:
        dict_values[tmp_val[1]] += 1

    for key,value in dict_values.items():
        tmp_list2.append([key, value])


        tmp_list2.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
        print(" Country " + " Wins " + "Years")
    for val in tmp_list2:
        print(" " + val[0] + " " + str(val[1]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an indentation issue. `f2` is being defined within `main`, meaning it cannot be used outside of `main`. You attempted to use it in the `for l in f2` loop, which resulted in your `NameError`.

Your `main` function only has one statement, `f2  = open("world_cup_champions.txt","r+")`, so you probably meant to define your program like this:

```
def main():
    f2  = open("world_cup_champions.txt","r+")

    dict_values ={}
    temp_list = []
    tmp_list2 = []

    for l in f2:
        temp_list.append(l.strip())
        temp_list = temp_list[1:]


    for val in temp_list:
        tmp_val = val.split(',')
        if tmp_val[1] not in dict_values:
            dict_values[tmp_val[1]] = 1
        else:
            dict_values[tmp_val[1]] += 1

    for key,value in dict_values.items():
        tmp_list2.append([key, value])


        tmp_list2.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
        print(" Country " + " Wins " + "Years")
    for val in tmp_list2:
        print(" " + val[0] + " " + str(val[1]))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you just wanted that one statement in `main`, but you wanted to use `f2` throughout the program, you could define `main` like this:

```
def main():
    global f2
    f2 = open("world_cup_champions.txt","r+")
```

The first statement, `global f2`, makes `main` define `f2` as a *global variable* rather than a *local variable* when it's called, which will allow you to use it throughout the program rather than just in that one function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't indented correctly, alternatively you can edit it slightly

```
def main():
    f2  = open("world_cup_champions.txt","r+")

    dict_values ={}
    temp_list = []
    tmp_list2 = []

    for l in f2:
        temp_list.append(l.strip())
        temp_list = temp_list[1:]


    for val in temp_list:
        tmp_val = val.split(',')
        if tmp_val[1] not in dict_values:
            dict_values[tmp_val[1]] = 1
    else:
        dict_values[tmp_val[1]] += 1

    for key,value in dict_values.items():
        tmp_list2.append([key, value])

    tmp_list2.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    print(" Country " + " Wins " + "Years")
    for val in tmp_list2:
        print(" " + val[0] + " " + str(val[1]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

alternatively, just do this

```
def main():
    return open("world_cup_champions.txt","r+")

dict_values ={}
temp_list = []
tmp_list2 = []

f2 = main()

for l in f2:
    temp_list.append(l.strip())
    temp_list = temp_list[1:]


for val in temp_list:
    tmp_val = val.split(',')
    if tmp_val[1] not in dict_values:
        dict_values[tmp_val[1]] = 1
else:
    dict_values[tmp_val[1]] += 1

for key,value in dict_values.items():
    tmp_list2.append([key, value])


    tmp_list2.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    print(" Country " + " Wins " + "Years")
for val in tmp_list2:
    print(" " + val[0] + " " + str(val[1]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

You indentation is off. You need to have all statements inline with the first one.

```
def main():
   f2  = open("world_cup_champions.txt","r+")
   dict_values ={}
   temp_list = []
   tmp_list2 = []
```

Comment: I am having a  problem  with is this line:
temp_list = temp_list[1:]

The first element gets added to the list. Then that statement takes from the 2nd element, in the 1st position until the end, making the list empty. This continues as it walks through the loop, essentially removing each element as it is added.